# Sproutcore menu

Tags: javascript, sproutcore

I'm starting to learn sproutcore(v1.7.1.beta). I am very concerned about the issues of proper implementation some things...one of them is main menu.

What the right way to do that?

I think I need to change state if menu item has been clicked, right? I tried to do it with `SC.TemplateCollectionView`, but can't understand, how to determine what item have been clicked?

My CollectionView:

```
App.MainMenuItemView = SC.TemplateCollectionView.extend({
  contentBinding: 'App.mainMenuController',
  mouseUp: function(){
    //
  }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by "main menu" here?  Do you want a popup?

Comment: No, not popup menu. I mean main application menu(toolbar), something like [this](https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com/img/48d7aa5488b1fb3458a8cebc54df15d3d96398da/687474703a2f2f662e73696d706c65736964656961732e636f6d2e62722f636f636f612d6265616e732f53656c65637461626c65546f6f6c6261722e706e67)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use

`SC.SegmentedView`.  Something like

```
topNav: SC.SegmentedView.extend({
    classNames: ['top-nav'],
    items: [
        {
            title: "App.title1".loc(),
            value: 1,
            action: 'action1'
        },
        {
            title: "App.title2".loc(),
            value: 2,
            action: 'action2'

        },
        ....
    ],
    itemTitleKey: 'title',
    itemValueKey: 'value',
    itemWidthKey: '85',
    itemActionKey: 'action', 
    valueBinding: 'Binding to current tab value'
})
```

You can specify an icon via `itemIconKey`....

Or just roll your own custom SC.View.

Comment: Where do you have to implement that action? (Sorry to gravedig.)